# row ID with grouped data, arranged by specific column

Tags: r, date, uniqueidentifier

Here is the reproducible dataset:

```
id<- c("U1", "U2", "U3", "U2", "U5", "U5")
date<- c("2020-02-01", "2020-05-06", "2020-04-01", "2020-07-09", "2020-11-01", "2020-12-01")
result<- c(1:6)
dt<- data.frame(id, date, result)
```

```
> dt
  id       date result
1 U1 2020-02-01      1
2 U2 2020-05-06      2
3 U3 2020-04-01      3
4 U2 2020-07-09      4
5 U5 2020-11-01      5
6 U5 2020-12-01      6
```

I want to create a loop (or maybe there is another way) that looks at the Unique ID's and test dates, and adds a new column to tell me which is the test number, ordered by those test dates. So the output would look like this:

```
  id       date result     type
1 U1 2020-02-01      1 Result 1
2 U2 2020-05-06      2 Result 1
3 U3 2020-04-01      3 Result 1
4 U2 2020-07-09      4 Result 2
5 U5 2020-11-01      5 Result 1
6 U5 2020-12-01      6 Result 2
```

U2 has two results, ordered by their test date, and U5 has two results, ordered by their test date. As a bonus question, I would also love to find the time difference between the various tests for each Unique ID, again as a separate column. So it would look like this:

```
id       date result     type       time
1 U1 2020-02-01      1 Result 1 First Test
2 U2 2020-05-06      2 Result 1 First Test
3 U3 2020-04-01      3 Result 1 First Test
4 U2 2020-07-09      4 Result 2    64 Days
5 U5 2020-11-01      5 Result 1 First Test
6 U5 2020-12-01      6 Result 2    30 Days
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `group_by(id)`, `arrange` by date, then use `row_number()`. It is always advisable to convert dates to proper date class columns before any transformations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

dt %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    mutate(type = glue("Result {row_number()}")) %>%
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  id    date       result type    
  <chr> <date>      <int> <glue>  
1 U1    2020-02-01      1 Result 1
2 U3    2020-04-01      3 Result 1
3 U2    2020-05-06      2 Result 1
4 U2    2020-07-09      4 Result 2
5 U5    2020-11-01      5 Result 1
6 U5    2020-12-01      6 Result 2
```

For the bonus question,we can use a simple subtraction `date - first(date)`:

```
dt %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    mutate(type = glue("Result {row_number()}"),
           time = date - first(date)) %>%
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 × 5
  id    date       result type     time   
  <chr> <date>      <int> <glue>   <drtn> 
1 U1    2020-02-01      1 Result 1  0 days
2 U3    2020-04-01      3 Result 1  0 days
3 U2    2020-05-06      2 Result 1  0 days
4 U2    2020-07-09      4 Result 2 64 days
5 U5    2020-11-01      5 Result 1  0 days
6 U5    2020-12-01      6 Result 2 30 days
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly. I did not know that grouping by ID's would lead to row numbers equal to that of the count of those unique ID's - I thought it would print rows 1-6. Can you explain why you used glue instead of paste? Again, thanks so much!

Comment: Once the data is grouped, all  subsequent operations consider the grouping. Think of grouping as we would with `split() %>% some_function %>% ""merge_back""`.

As for my preference for `glue()`, I just think it allows simpler and more readable coding of dynamically generated strings. Compare `paste0('Result ', row_number())` with `glue("Result {row_number()}")`. The seccond is just simpler. As the `paste/glue` operation gets more complex (as with multiple arguments to `paste`), `glue` starts shining brighter. It does require loading an additional package, though.